# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

## [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project cloud-config-server: There are test failures.

I am running a maven project I ran a simple command and got the following error:-

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project cloud-config-server: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\cloud-config-server\cloud-config-server\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the '-e' switch
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the '-X' switch to enable verbose output
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This is my pom.xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microServicesDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cloud-config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

I am using visual studios code and my java version is java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS

I tried searching the solution for this error and got bunch of solutions but none of them worked for me

Comment: First check your failing tests... and furthermore upgrade the maven-surefire-plugin version to 3.0.0...